# Fields searchable but not filterable

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering how I can end up with the first query failing while the second matches.

**This does not match**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all": {}},
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "registration_references": ["impedit-40aa"]
            }
          },
          {"term": {"is_deleted": false}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**This matches**

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {"registration_references": "impedit-40aa"}
      },
      "filter": {"term": {"is_deleted": false}}
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have a clue on what's missing ?

Comment: The first uses a `terms` query (i.e. where the input is not analyzed), while the second uses a `match` query (i.e. where the input is analyzed). It's highly probably that the `registration_references` field is an analyzed string, right?

Comment: impedit-40aa will be separated by the default analyzer to be impedit 40aa filter match by exact values and will not find. Just to understand try to search by impedit using filter. If you have to match the exact value using filter change the analyze of the field to be not_analyzed

Comment: @Val, right. The problème is that `registration_references` is analyzed. @Waldemar exact. Without hyphen, it works. Thank you all !

Comment: Yes, so you simply need to change the mapping of that field to `"index":"not_analyzed"` and reindex your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Val and Waldemar, the `registration_references` field is analyzed, this breaks exact term match.